# c++ thread_local static std::vector<> having _M_start = NULL

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, stl

So I have a function that works with the following variable.

```
std::vector<std::vector<indexValue>> asnGeoLists(delegationIndex.size());
```

the function gets called by operator<() during a std::sort on a vector. I multithreaded the sort and the function continues to work fine.

I changed the variable to be thread_local static in order to avoid some overhead allocating the outside vector each time the function is called and the program crashes. Debugging shows the following

```
#0  0x000000010000257d in std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::~vector (this=0x0) at stl_vector.h:425
```

I followed the stack and found it's being called from within

```
#5  0x000000010002f4ab in std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >::~vector (this=0x109b78f28)
```

and was able to verify that this is of the type above (and there's nothing else of that type). I went into this frame and found that

```
$5 = ('std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >' * const) 0x109b78f28
(gdb) print *this
$6 = {
  <std::_Vector_base<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >> = {
_M_impl = {
  <allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >> = {
    <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
  members of std::_Vector_base<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >::_Vector_impl: 
  _M_start = 0x0, 
  _M_finish = 0x109b70003, 
  _M_end_of_storage = 0x109b7a178
}
  }, <No data fields>}
```

so _M_start = NULL. My first guess was that something was being free'd twice but I wrote some test code and debugged it and it seems that in the test code after a vector is deleted _M_start still has the old value. I've also verified that in some example code that _M_start is a pointer to the first element.

Just before the end of the function I dump the pointers to the outside vector and the first element of the vector and neither are NULL.

So how could _M_start be getting set to NULL after the function's last exit but before the destructor gets called as pthread_exit() is cleaning up? (Or am I missing something else entirely here?)

Edit: I'm using 
bash-3.2$ g++-mp-4.9 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-mp-4.9
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/work/gcc-4.9.2/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc49 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc49 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.9 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.9 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc49/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-isl=/opt/local --disable-isl-version-check --with-cloog=/opt/local --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc49 4.9.2_1'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.2_1) 
bash-3.2$

The code below appears to trigger the problem though it only happens occasionally.

The last parameter to threadSort() is the number of threads to use. Removing the thread_local static from sortable::score() does not appear to trigger the problem.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void printVector(typename std::vector<T>::iterator& begin, typename std::vector<T>::iterator& end) 
{
    for(auto e = begin; e < end; e++) {
        std::cout << *e << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void threadSort(typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin, typename std::vector<T>::iterator end, unsigned int t)
{
    unsigned int                threadLength, i;

    if(end - begin < 2*t || t == 1) {
        std::sort(begin, end);
        return;
    }
    threadLength = (end - begin) / t;
    std::thread threads[t];
    for(i=0; i< t-1; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(std::sort<typename std::vector<T>::iterator>, begin + i*threadLength, begin + (i+1)*threadLength);
    }
    threads[i] = std::thread(std::sort<typename std::vector<T>::iterator>, begin + i*threadLength, end);
    for(i=0; i < t; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    for(i=0; i<t-2; i++) {
        std::inplace_merge(begin, begin + (i+1)*threadLength, begin + (i+2)*threadLength);
    }
    std::inplace_merge(begin, begin + (i+1)*threadLength, end);
    return;
}

class sortable {
    public:
        bool operator<(const sortable& r) const { return this->score() < r.score(); }
        int_fast64_t score() const {
            static thread_local std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>      vvi(21);

            for(unsigned int i; i < vvi.size(); i++) {
                vvi[i].push_back(7);
                vvi[i].push_back(9);
            }
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vvi.size(); i++) {
                vvi[i].resize(0);
            }
            return 8;
        }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<sortable>   foo(500);
    threadSort<sortable>(foo.begin(), foo.end(), 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Because otherwise it might be hard (or even impossible) for us to check this and to help you in a meaningful way. Also, what compiler are you using, and which version of it?